# Sql How to limit query with postional argument?

Tags: php, mysql

My code look like:

```php
$sql = '
SELECT ads.ad_id 
  FROM ads_day_by_day 
  LEFT 
  JOIN ads 
    ON ads_day_by_day.ad_id = ads.ad_id 
 WHERE ads_day_by_day.date >= ? 
   AND ads_day_by_day.date <= ? 
 GROUP 
    BY ads_day_by_day.ad_id 
 LIMIT ?';
$statement = $this->em->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute($from, $to, 10]);
$ads = $statement->fetchAllAssociative();
```

And I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''10'' at line 1
```

Could you let me know what I am doing wrong? Why I am getting this type of error?
It is very important to use positional argument, no named!

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate. If you want DISTINCT results, use DISTINCT!

Comment: My query in real has 10 lines :) 
Do you know the answer to my question?

Comment: Your Common Sense's answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990857/reference-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdo#15991623 covers this.

Comment: I use dbal doctrine, where can I paste it?

Comment: I know nothing whatsover about that :-(